# Power Pivot Can't get data from the data model

Tags: powerpivot

I've had my PC since Sept 2014 and really want to use Power Pivot in Excel. I have Windows 8.1 64bit running stand alone Excel 2013 32bit (purchased Sept 2014)

I have never been able to get Power Pivot to load, the Add-in appears on the ribbon but only produces the errors described below.

I have MySQL installed, Visual Studio 2010 for Office Runtime (x64), Open Office with text only enabled.

I've run the Configuration Analyzer Tool (OffCAT) which only showed a problem with Outlook which is fine ( I think! ) as I don't use it and reinstalled both Excel and the add-in.

If anyone can shed some light on or solve this problem it would be greatly appreciated. I've read somewhere (forgot to bookmark) about editing script in one of the config files as there could be an accidental 'space' in the code, if I could find where I read that maybe that would help or solve this. I see somebody posted the exact same error elsewhere a few months back but received no answer so maybe this can't be rectified.

Here are the errors I recieve:

```
"We couldn't get data from the Data Model. Here's the error message we got:
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Analysis.Services.XmlaClient' threw an exception.
Configuration system failed to initialize.
Root element is missing. (C\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine\config)
Root element is missing."
```

When I close this error another box appears:

```
Sorry, PowerPivot can't openthe Data Model because there was a COM exceptionwhile opening. 
You might be opening a workbook on a corrupt installation of excel. Click Details for more information.
```

When I click 'Details' this appears:

```
============================
Error Message:
============================
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
============================
Call Stack:
============================
   at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.CannotUpgrade(GeminiWorkbook geminiWb, WorkbookConnection wbConn, String& message)
   at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.LoadSandboxAfterConnection(String errorCache)
   at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.LoadSafeSandboxAfterConnection(String errorCache)
   at Microsoft.Office.PowerPivot.ExcelAddIn.InProcServer.LoadOLEDBConnection(Boolean raiseCompleteEvent, String errorCache)
============================
```

Answer (score 1):

I received a pointer from someone called 'scottsen' over at Mr.Excel who suggested I re-installed Microsoft.Net 4 framework.

So that's what I did and now it works just fine (til I find a way to break it!).

Case solved.